# need trigger_id for more than 3 seconds in slack api

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am currently using the slack api through slack commands in a node application, and within my request there is a `trigger_id` which I need to use to open a modal. However, I am not getting ideal results because the `trigger_id` only lasts for 3 seconds, and I need it to last longer (perhaps 10 seconds). It takes too long for the request to go from slack to the API gateway, and to my lambda function. Is there any way I can make it so that I can open a modal with a trigger_id that has lasted for more than 3 seconds, or is there a possible workaround such as creating a new trigger_id possibly?

Answer (score -1):

When certain events and interactions occur between users and your app, you'll receive a trigger_id as part of the interaction payload.

 **Triggers expire in three seconds.** Use them before you lose them.

Depending on the source, the interaction payload your app receives may contain a `response_url`.

 This **response_url** is unique to each payload, and can be used to publish messages back to the place where the interaction happened.

> If you don't receive a response_url in your interaction payload—for
> example, the payload from a global shortcut will not contain one—you
> can use a trigger_id and a modal to get one for your app.

**https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#modal_response_url**

Comment: but how would I use the response_url to open the modal? To open a modal you need a trigger_id